# PHP + posting links in tweets - need I check the length of the tweet?

Tags: php, twitter, hyperlink, tweets

Twitter use its own URL shortener - the result of the link "20 chars long link".
What I am curious - I wanna share to Twitter with using PHP some of my articles - need I check the length of the link to the article?

Real example - my title of an article has 120 chars. Link to my article has 25 chars. Limit of the tweet is 140 chars. URL shortener transform each link into 20 characters.

Do I need to solve in this case the length of the tweet and can I rely that **each link in the tweet = 20 characters**?

Or the URL shortener by Twitter is working only when someone manually type a tweet and the URL shortener doesn't works in their API?

Comment: should be 20 chars until they run out of available short-codes and have to boost the length again to increase the available code space.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter now limits tweets to 117 characters if you include a link(https), remaining 23 characters it will take to wrap the url(https) to t.co format. Effectively here you get 117 character for https links and 118 characters for non-https links.

source-link: http://www.geek.com/news/twitter-now-limits-tweets-to-117-characters-if-you-include-a-link-1540340/